# Can you help me clarify Geolocation usage and terms of service?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to use google geolocation in the following manner:

1. User will submit state,county,city,zip or any combination, I will
   parse it into a string address and send via request url:
   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=STRING&sensor=false
2. I parse the JSON result and verify the location provided is
   complete and correct
3. Result parsed as array will not be plotted
   on a map, they will be stored in DB as valid user address.
4. Geolocation request is available once user registered to the website
   for free, using mail+password.

Can you please verify I will not be breaching any TOS ?
If so, how can I mend it ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the required login:

http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/maps/terms.html#section_9_1
*9.1.3 Examples.

(a) You can require users to log in to your Maps API Implementation if you do not require users to pay a fee.*

**Everything is fine, as long as everybody who want's to register at your page may do that**

### BUT

Given the fact that you do not use the results with a map:

http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_1
*For example, you must not use geocodes obtained through the Service
except in conjunction with a Google map*

What do you do with the results, why do you store them in a DB?

Comment: I need a valid user location in (state/county/city/zip) format because other users need to look for him using the same parameters. Instead of searching in boundaries, which google doesnt provide, I will run a simple string match. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Sorry for nit-picking... but it's certain I don't need to show results on a map, correct ?

Comment: It's not about showing the result on a map, it's about using the results with a map. I better say: you need to use the result to build an application that's based on a map. Following your description you don't do that, so it's not legal to use the results that way. Except the other users "look for him" on a google-maps-based application.